# get all atributes in nested object that have auto relationship

Tags: php, laravel, rest, nested

I am creating a `Rest API` project that I have an Artist that have a Musical Genre `object` as an `attribute`, and I created these two `classes` like this:

Artist:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Artist extends Model
{
    public $table = 'artist';
    public $timestamps = false;
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', '...'
    ];

    //...

    public function musical_genre() {
        return $ this-> belongsTo (MusicalGenre::class, 'musical_genre');
    }
}
```

Musical Genre:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MusicalGenre extends Model
{
    public $table = 'musical_genre';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', '...'
    ];

    // ...

    function parent_genre(){
        return $this->hasMany(MusicalGenre::class, 'parent_genre');
    }
}
```

As you can see, Genre Musical have an auto relationship, because an Genre Musical can have an Parent Genre. This works nice, but the response I get is like this:

```
{
    "artist": [
        {
            "id": 14,
            "name": "Britney Spears",
            "musical_genre": {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "electropop",
                "parent_genre": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But I wish it could be like this:

```
{
    "artist": [
        {
            "id": 14,
            "name": "Britney Spears",
            "musical_genre": {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "electropop",
                "parent_genre": {
                    "id:" 1,
                    "name": "pop"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In `controller` I have this line to call Artist with Genre:

```
$artist= Artist::with(['...', 'musical_genre'])->get();
```

I already tried to call it with `musical_genre.parent_genre` but I got a empty parent.

There is a way to make the response like I wished in `Laravel`, with all atributes and not only the id? I didnt found how can I do this in `Laravel docs`.

**EDIT:**

I already tried using

`$artist->load('parent_genre');`

too.

**EDIT 2:**

My last try was in `show()` `method` inside the `controller`, like this:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $artist = Artist::with(['login', 'musical_genre'])->findOrFail($id);

    $musical_genre = MusicalGenre::findOrFail($artist->musical_genre); 

    $parent_genre = MusicalGenre::findOrFail($musical_genre->parent_genre); 

    if ($parent_genre){
        $musical_genre->parent_genre = $parent_genre;
    }

    $artist->musical_genre = $musical_genre;

    return response()->json(['artist' => $artist], 200);
}
```

And I got the same response, just with the `"parent_genre": 1`. I tried to get only `$musical_genre->parent_genre` and I got this body:

```
"musical_genre": {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "electropop",
    "parent_genre": {
        "id:" 1,
        "name": "pop"
        "parent_genre": null
    }
}
```

like I wished. Maybe it's some `Laravel` limitation, not showing `artist->musical_genre->parent_genre` full `body`?

Comment: You shouldn't name relationships the same as their respective columns, that only causes problems. Rename your relationships and try again.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, thanks for the advice. how could i name it? does exist a convention to do it?

Comment: The convention is to use `musical_genre_id` and `parent_genre_id` as column names. Then you can name the relationships `musical_genre` and `parent_genre`. Is renaming your columns still possible?

Comment: yes, i am coding it from scratch. i didnt understood if i have to change the values at the database or at php code?

Comment: You have to change the database migrations.

Comment: Does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `$with` attribute to the `MusicalGenre` model like so:

```
class MusicalGenre extends Model
{
    public $table = 'musical_genre';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $with = ['parent_genre:id,name'];
    .....
}
```

See: https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#property_with

When you call the `MusicalGenre` model, it loads the `parent_genre` automatically. The 'id,name' in it limits the retrieved model to the two fields, if you want to to load all, just use only 'parent_genre' only.

Simply call it this way and you have it loaded with the response:

```
$artist= Artist::with('musical_genre')->get();
```

Comment: i tried with this $with attribute, but i get "parent_genre:": [] at the response :(

Comment: @mhery Are you sure that `parent_genre` is the foreign key on `musical_genre` table? And also have you checked if there's any data at all in `parent_genre` table (that matches the `id` on `musical_genre`?

Comment: I got a catch in your relationship method: `parent_genre()` `$this->hasMany(MusicalGenre::class, 'parent_genre')` you're using 'MusicalGenre' not 'ParentGenre'. did you intend that?

Comment: yes, because parent_genre's class is MusicalGenre too. it's a self relationship

Answer (score 0):

Please try this for nested eager loading:

```
    $artist= Artist::with(['musical_genre'=> function ($query) {
        $query->with(['parent_genre']);
    }])->get();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i tried it, but i get "parent_genre": [] at the response, too...

Comment: And you are sure that you have parent_genre on your test model ? Means you can call a `$artist->musical_genre->parent_genre` ?

Comment: i defined parent_genre inside musical genre $fillable and in hasMany relationship. i tried to call $artist[0]->musical_genre->parent_genre but i got ErrorException: Trying to get property 'parent_genre' of non-object. I am really lost :|

Comment: Try $artist[0]->musical_genre()->get()->parent_genre()->get()

Comment: i tried but it didnt worked. i was wondering if i have to specify in your code the relation between parent_genre and id...